# What is the equation for beta1 prime, beta2 prime and the normalizing constant in the following beta distribution?

Tags: math, statistics, bayesian, beta-distribution, probability-distribution

Can someone tell me what the separate equations for beta1 prime (B_1) and beta2 prime (B_2) and the normalizing constant are in this beta distribution? How does one go about computing them?

```
θ ^(k+β_1 -1) (1 − θ)(n−k+β_2 −1)/B(k+β_1, n-k + k+β_2)
```

If you could help me, I'd be very thankful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Some preliminaries:

The Beta distribution pdf is:

[ (\theta)^(\alpha - 1)*(1- \ theta)^(\beta - 1) ] / B(\alpha, \beta)

Where:

- \theta is the random variable between 0 and 1 that we usually try to solve for. For example, using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) or MAP estimation.
- \alpha and \beta are parameters for the Beta distribution, called the shape and rate
- B(\alpha, \beta) is the Beta function - NOT to be confused with the Beta probability distribution. The [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) function is:

B(a,b) =  [ Gamma(a)*Gamma(b) ] / Gamma(a+b)

Where Gamma is the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) function, given by:

Gamma(a) = (a-1)!

For positive integers a, b. There is a more complicated form when a,b are not integers. So you can calculate the Beta function using whatever built in factorial function your software program uses.

So in your case, \alpha = k + Beta_1, and \beta = n - k + Beta_2. This looks like a posterior distribution for a Beta prior with Binomial Likelihood.

I assume you're performing a [Bayesian inference](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10701/lecture/technote2_betabinomial.pdf). If that's the case, then usually we set:

- \alpha = "Number of successes"
- \beta = "Number of failures" = "Number of total observations - number of successes"

when performing Bernoulli experiments, i.e. like coin flipping or users subscribing to a website.

If you provide more information on what you're trying to solve, perhaps we can be of more help.

Comment: Thanks! This helps!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if its what you are looking for